# Safe primes subgroup in Diffie–Hellman key exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, group-theory, safe-prime

I'm trying to understand how the safe primes numbers are used in Diffie–Hellman key exchange. According to wiki:

> The order of G should have a large prime factor to prevent use of the
> Pohlig–Hellman algorithm to obtain a or b. For this reason, a Sophie
> Germain prime q is sometimes used to calculate p = 2q + 1, called a
> safe prime, since the order of G is then only divisible by 2 and q. g
> is then sometimes chosen to generate the order q subgroup of G, rather
> than G, so that the Legendre symbol of ga never reveals the low order
> bit of a. A protocol using such a choice is for example IKEv2

I'm trying to figure out the context of the paragraph above with small numbers.
`q=11` is Sophie Germain prime -> safe prime `p=23`. Than I need to find `g` so  `g is then sometimes chosen to generate the order q subgroup of G`.

- Shall I find `g` so `g^11 (mod 23)` will result in a number within the order-11 subgroup?
- Or shall I abandon GF(23) and operate in GF(11)?

If you can provide a clear example with some small numbers that illustrate my misunderstanding, please, do it.

Comment: For the Legendre leak [Decisional Diffie-Hellman: compute Legendre symbol of $g^{ab}$ from $g^a$ and $g^b$?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31378/18298)

Comment: I think this covers first dot. [How to find generator 
in a cyclic group?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9006/18298)

Comment: For safe primes, $g=2$ generates the subgroup of size $q$ if $p \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$, it generates the entire group of size $2q$ if $p \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$.  In your example, $23 \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$, and so $g=2$ generates a group of size 11.

Comment: @poncho `=2 generates the subgroup of size  if ≡7(mod8)` how do 7 and 8 appear here?

Comment: @pacman: from the law of quadratic residuosity.  That is considerably deeper than what is currently puzzling you - I suggest you don't worry about it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, when you have a safe prime $p > 5$, then all the values between $1$ and $p-1$ fall into four categories:

- Values $g$ that have the order $p-1$; these values generate all values between $1$ and $p-1$, that is, $g^x = a \pmod p$ has a solution $x$ for all values $1 \le e < p$.  These values of $g$ are not quadratic residues, that is, there is no value $a$ such that $a^2 = g \pmod{p}$
- Values $g$ that have the order $q$; these values generate half the values between $1$ and $p-1$, that is, $g^x = a \bmod p$ has a solution $x$ for half the values of $a$.  These values $g$ are quadratic residues (that is, there is a value $b$ such that $b^2 = g \pmod{p}$, and every value in the generated group is also a quadratic residue.
- The value $-1$ (aka $p-1$)
- The value 1

Hence, if we pick a value $g$ which is neither $1$ nor $p-1$, then the order will always be either $p-1$ or $q$.

With that in mind:

> Shall I find $g$ so $g^{11} \pmod {23}$ will result in a number within the order-11 subgroup?

Well, $g^q \bmod p$ will always be either $1$ or $p-1$.  If it is $1$, then $g$ has order $q$ (or $g=1$).  If it is $p-1$, then $g$ has order $p-1$ (or $g=p-1$).

So, it can be used to test $g$ to see which group it generates; however you wouldn't want to use the value $g^q \bmod p$.

You asked for an example with small numbers; we find that $2^{11} \bmod 23 = 1$, hence $g=2$ generates the subgroup of size 11.  On the other hand, $5^{11} \bmod 23 = 22$, hence $g=5$ generates the entire group (of size 22).

That works as a test, however you don't need to go to that amount of effort.

If you're looking for a value that generates the prime sized subgroup (and not the subgroup of size 2 :-), one easy option is to pick $g=4$.  That's obviously not in the first, third or fourth category, and so it must be in the second.

Another, rather less obvious, option is if $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$; if that is true, then $g=2$ also generates the subgroup).

> Or shall I abandon GF(23) and operate in GF(11)?

Nope; all work is done in $GF(p)$

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. Can u please explain why the fact that `2^11 mod 23 = 1` leads to the conclusion that it generates a subgroup of size 11?

Comment: and one more detail to clarify: is `Legendre leak` a main reason behind using of subgroup of order `q` or are there any important reasons behind it?

Comment: @pacman: as for why $2^{11} \bmod 23 = 1$ tells us that the subgroup is size 11; well, we know that $2 \ne 1, 22$, and so cases 3, 4 do not apply.  In case 1, the value $g$ has order 22, but this calculation shows that 2 has a smaller order, so the only possibility left is 11.  Another way of looking at it: the order of the value $g$ (the smallest value $x>0$ s.t. $g^x = 1$ is the size of the subgroup $g$ generates.  We see that $2^{11} = 1$, and so the order of 2 must be a factor of 11.  Now, 11 is prime, so the only possibilities are 1 and 11; it's not 1 ($2^1\ne 1$), so the order must be 11

Comment: I got it. Here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47266/103942 you explained the difference between subgroup order for `p` and `2p`. Now I realise why subgroup with `2p` order leaks 1 bit of the exponent. These facts really helped to connect the dots. Btw, maybe you can recommend some books that cover this topic?